# Error en JAVA creacion de arrayList incompatible types: String cannot be converted to sucursal ----

Tags: java, java-swing, arraylist, constructor, jtextfield

¿Que significa el error y como puedo resolverlo? Es una base de datos de un banco en la cual tengo que usar un tipo "sucursal" pero no puedo utilizarlo add ese tipo A Mi arrayList

```
ArrayList Array_Asesores = new ArrayList();
```

Aqui esta el codigo porfavorrr...

```
public class asesor {
    private int IDASESOR;
    private sucursal Sucursal;
    private String Nombre_asesor;
    private String Direccion;
    private String email;
    private int num_cel;
    private int edad;

    //Constructor
    public asesor(int IDASESOR_, String Nombre_asesor_, String Direccion_, sucursal Sucursal_, String email_, int num_cel_, int edad_) {
        IDASESOR = IDASESOR_;
        Nombre_asesor = Nombre_asesor_;
        Direccion = Direccion_;
        Sucursal = Sucursal_;
        email=email_;
        num_cel= num_cel_;
        edad = edad_;
    }
    public int getIDASESOR(){
         return IDASESOR;    
     }
     public void setIDASESOR (int Idasesor){
     this.IDASESOR=Idasesor;
     }

     public String getNombre_asesor(){
     return Nombre_asesor;
     }
     public void setNombre_asesor(String Nombre_ase){
     this.Nombre_asesor=Nombre_ase;
     }

     public String getDireccion(){
     return Direccion;
     }
     public void setDireccion(String Direc){
     this.Direccion=Direc;
     }

     public sucursal getSucursal(){
     return Sucursal;
     }
     public void setSucursal(sucursal Sucu){
     this.Sucursal=Sucu;
     }




private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        /* IDASESOR = IDASESOR_;
            Nombre_asesor = Nombre_asesor_;
            Direccion = Direccion_;
            Sucursal = Sucursal_;
            email=email_;
            num_cel= num_cel_;
            edad = edad_;
        */
        String IDAS1=IDAS.getText();
         String NOM1=NOM.getText();
         String DIR1=DIR.getText();
         String SUC1=SUC.getText();
         String EMA1=EMA.getText(); 
         String NUMC1=NUMC.getText();
         String EDA1=EDA.getText();

          if (!IDAS1.isEmpty()) {
              if (!NOM1.isEmpty()) {
                  if (!DIR1.isEmpty()) {
                      if (!SUC1.isEmpty()) {
                          if (!EMA1.isEmpty()) {
                              if (!NUMC1.isEmpty()) {
                                  if (!EDA1.isEmpty()) {

                                      int IDAS2=Integer.parseInt(IDAS1);
                                       int NUMC2=Integer.parseInt(NUMC1);
                                        int EDA2=Integer.parseInt(EDA1);




                                      asesor nuevo = new asesor(IDAS2, NOM1, DIR1, SUC1, EMA1, NUMC2, EDA2);
                                      Array_Asesores.add(nuevo);
                                      DAT.setText("Datos guardados con exito");



                             }else{
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caja de texto Edad esta vacía");
                               EDA.requestFocusInWindow();  
                                  }
                             }else{
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caja de texto celular esta vacía");
                               NUMC.requestFocusInWindow();
                                 }
                             }else{
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caja de texto Email esta vacía");
                                EMA.requestFocusInWindow();
                            }
                        }else{
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caja de texto Sucursal esta vacío");
                            SUC.requestFocusInWindow();
                        }
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caja de texto dirección vacío");
                        DIR.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caja de texto nombre asesor esta vacío");
                    NOM.requestFocusInWindow();
                }
          }else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Caja de texto Id asesor esta vacía");
              IDAS.requestFocusInWindow();
          }
        }
```

Necesito entregar el trabajo hoy por la tarde amigos, Gracias por su ayuda

Aqui les dejo el codigo de de la otra clase "Sucursal" que es la que quiero utilizar en mi otra clase "Asesor"

```
package clases;
/** * * @author Vivian Herrera */ public class sucursal {

private int IDSUCURSAL;
private String Nombre_sucursal;
private String Direccion_sucursal;
private int Telefono;
private String Localidad;


    public sucursal(int IDSUCURSAL_, String Nombre_sucursal_, String Direccion_sucursal_,int T,String L) {
        IDSUCURSAL = IDSUCURSAL_;
        Nombre_sucursal = Nombre_sucursal_;
        Direccion_sucursal = Direccion_sucursal_;
        Localidad = L;
        Telefono = T;
    }

    public int getIDSUCURSAL(){
         return IDSUCURSAL;    
     }
     public void setIDSUCURSAL (int IDSUCURSAL){
     this.IDSUCURSAL=IDSUCURSAL;
     }

     public String getNombre_sucursal(){
     return Nombre_sucursal;
     }
     public void setNombre_sucursal(String Nombre_sucursal){
     this.Nombre_sucursal=Nombre_sucursal;
     }

     public String getDireccion_sucursal(){
     return Direccion_sucursal;
     }
     public void setDireccion_sucursal(String Direccion_sucursal){
     this.Direccion_sucursal=Direccion_sucursal;
     }

     public String getLocalidad(){
 return Localidad;
     }
     public void setLocalidad(String Local){
     this.Localidad=Local;
     }

     public int getTelefono(){
         return Telefono;    
     }
     public void setTelefono (int Tele){
     this.Telefono=Tele;
     }
}
```

Comment: Exactamente en qué linea te marca el error, debe decir cuando te manda el error.

Comment: Aquí
asesor nuevo = new asesor(IDAS2, NOM1, DIR1, SUC1, EMA1, NUMC2, EDA2); sr1871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así como te dijo el otro usuario, tu error es que en el constructor declaraste un parámetro como sucursal(El cual por costumbre debería estar con mayúsculas por ser una clase).

> asesor nuevo = new asesor(IDAS2, NOM1, DIR1, SUC1, EMA1, NUMC2, EDA2);

Donde dice **SUC1**, debería estar recibiendo un objeto sucursal( new sucursal() ), sin embargo le estas pasando un **SUC1** que pertenece al tipo **String**.

**Cómo lo arreglas?**

**a)** Cambiando el tipo de parámetro del constructor por un String.

**b)** Cambiando lo que declarás en el asesor, y en vez de **SUC1** le pones **new sucursal()**. (Solo que te va a tirar error en algunas lineas que hayas utilizado métodos que dependen de **String**)

En conclusión, si no tenés mucha experiencia en java te diría que cambies el constructor a String y que de apoco vayas viendo las costumbres que se utilizan que son varias.

**============= Anexo: Puntos a tener en cuenta =============**

Dado que hay algunas cosas que vi en tu preguntas están flojas te voy a dejar las tres clases, las copias en sus respectivas clases y le das **Run as java application** en **BancoControlador**.

Esto no está bien ya que me estoy ampliando en mi respuesta pero así ves un ejemplo íntegro. No te solucioné lo que tenés en el **Button** porque es algo tenés que procesar vos, seguramente llamando al nombre del banco como indico en en el ejemplo.

Clase **Sucursal**

```
public class Sucursal {

    private int id;
    private String nombreSucursal;
    private String direccionSucursal;
    private int telefono;
    private String localidad;

    public Sucursal() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombreSucursal() {
        return nombreSucursal;
    }

    public void setNombreSucursal(String nombreSucursal) {
        this.nombreSucursal = nombreSucursal;
    }

    public String getDireccionSucursal() {
        return direccionSucursal;
    }

    public void setDireccionSucursal(String direccionSucursal) {
        this.direccionSucursal = direccionSucursal;
    }

    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

}
```

Clase **Asesor**

```
public class Asesor {

    private int id;
    private Sucursal Sucursal;
    private String nombre;
    private String direccion;
    private String email;
    private int telefono;
    private int edad;

    public Asesor(int id, Sucursal sucursal, String nombre, String direccion, String email, int telefono,
            int edad) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        Sucursal = sucursal;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.email = email;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Sucursal getSucursal() {
        return Sucursal;
    }
    public void setSucursal(Sucursal sucursal) {
        Sucursal = sucursal;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public int getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }
    public void setTelefono(int telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

}
```

Clase **BancoControlador**

```
public class BancoControlador {

    public BancoControlador() {

        /* Creamos la sucursal que le vamos a pasar por parámetro al Asesor */
        Sucursal sucursal = new Sucursal();
        sucursal.setDireccionSucursal("Dirección de la misma");
        sucursal.setLocalidad("blabla");
        sucursal.setNombreSucursal("Sucursal1");

        /* Acá creamos el arrayList que no entiendo para qué lo necesitás, osea donde la vas a usar, sin embargo te digo que podés cargar varios objetos de Sucursal e iterar sobre los mismos */
        ArrayList<Sucursal> listadoSucursales = new ArrayList<>();
        listadoSucursales.add(sucursal);

        /* Le pasamos por parámetro la sucursal que acabamos de crear */
        Asesor asesor = new Asesor(1, sucursal, "Armando", "Springfield 252", "ejemplo@hotmail.com", 1551112535, 21);

        /*
         * Como ejemplo nomás ponemos dentro del constructor el método que llama al
         * objeto Sucursal que a su vez tiene sus atributos como nombre direccion etc,
         */

        System.out.println(asesor.getSucursal().getNombreSucursal());

        /*
         * Fijate que hay un método que llama a la sucursal que le pasamos de parámetro
         * y otra que llama al nombre de ésa sucursal
         */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Creamos una instancia de esta misma clase y le damos Run as java application
         */
        BancoControlador bc = new BancoControlador();

    }

}
```

1) Fijáte que en la variables se utiliza camelCase, se empieza con minusculas y hay separaciones con mayúsculas, no utilices guión bajo para nombrar variables.

2) Las clases siempre deberían empezar con mayúsculas, al igual que los constructores si existieran.

Comment: amigo no necesito cambiar los tipos de parametros, por que lo que tengo que hacer es usar la otra clase en esa clase
instanciarlas mejor dicho

Comment: Identificar y crear las clases de un banco, que maneja diferentes sucursales, cada sucursal tiene la capacidad de manejar varias cuentas bancarias de sus clientes, estas cuentas pueden ser de tipo corriente o ahorros, asi mismo cada sucursal es capaz de manejar varios asesores, sin embargo un asesor actúa en una sola sucursal

este es la tarea que nos han colocado

Comment: Bueno ahi es donde hay un tema que quizás le estas pifiando, Cuando pasás una Sucursal como parametro, le estás pasando toda la sucursal, sin embargo te voy a explicar editando mi respuesta, por último te digo que si la duda o el error de porqué te tiraba error se solventó que cierres la pregunta dando como respondida por el otro usuario que también estuvo acertada o por mi, ahora veo si puedo profundizar un poco.

Comment: oK MUCHAS GRACIAS ESPERARE TU RESPUESTA..    
 :)

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias compa

Comment: Que significado tiene el super?

Comment: super();

se encuentra en la primera linea del constructor?

Comment: Si, pero no lo necesitás porque no está heredando de ninguna clase, me olvidé de borrarlo.

Answer (score 2):

En tu constructor de asesor el cuarto parametro es una sucursal

```
public asesor(int IDASESOR_, String Nombre_asesor_, String Direccion_, sucursal Sucursal_, String email_, int num_cel_, int edad_)
```

Tú le estás enviando un String

```
  asesor nuevo = new asesor(IDAS2, NOM1, DIR1, SUC1, EMA1, NUMC2, EDA2);

String SUC1=SUC.getText(); // cuarto parametro es String
```

Como consejo ten buenas prácticas, las clases van con UpperCamelCase y las variables con lowCamelCase.

Comment: Identificar y crear las clases de un banco, que maneja diferentes sucursales, cada sucursal tiene la capacidad de manejar varias cuentas bancarias de sus clientes, estas cuentas pueden ser de tipo corriente o ahorros, asi mismo cada sucursal es capaz de manejar varios asesores, sin embargo un asesor actúa en una sola sucursal

Answer (score 0):

Ok chicos
yo comprendo sus respuestas, pero no me han comprendido, lo que necesito es instanciar ambas clases, llamando a la clase sucursal en la clase asesor